# How can I control gvim toolbar icon in vimrc

Tags: vim, macvim

I have a shared vim personal folder used by Windows, Linux and Mac (maintained by github)

I have put some icons in ~/.vim/bitmaps so the givm will load icons for the toolbar

However the icons on Mac-Vim does work well,

How can I control mac-vim not loading those bitmaps in vimrc file?